# How to decrease contrast with android bitmap?

Tags: android, image-processing, brightness, contrast

This is the code which I use to change contrast and brightness of image. I can increase and decrease brightness of image with that because it takes -255 to 255 value for brightness and I can increase contrast with 0 to 10 value of it but I can't decrease contrast as in this code it does not take -ve value for contrast. so how can I decrease contrast?

```
/**
         * 
         * @param bmp input bitmap
         * @param contrast 0..10 1 is default
         * @param brightness -255..255 0 is default
         * @return new bitmap
         */
        public static Bitmap changeBitmapContrastBrightness(Bitmap bmp, float contrast, float brightness)
        {
            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
                    {
                        contrast, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
                        0, contrast, 0, 0, brightness,
                        0, 0, contrast, 0, brightness,
                        0, 0, 0, 1, 0
                    });

            Bitmap ret = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(ret);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);
            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: The values are float, have you tried values between 0.0f and 1.0f for the contrast?

Comment: can you guess which range between 0.0f to 10.0f  is for decrease contrast?